Java DateTimeFormatter problems
I have the following method, which takes a date string and tries for formate it to a LocalDateTime object:
(Locale is Norwegian)
public static LocalDateTime parseDatoLocalDateTime2(String datoString, String pattern, String language) {
    DateTimeFormatter formatter = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
        .parseCaseInsensitive()
        .appendPattern(pattern)
        .toFormatter(Locale.forLanguageTag(language));
    return LocalDateTime.parse(datoString, formatter);
}

As far as I know, these are the correct "format codes" to use:
yyyy = 2024
yy = 24
MMMM = April
MMM = Apr
MM = 04
dd = 09
d = 9

So, this works:
String testdato1 = "8. 04. 2024 15:32";
parseDatoLocalDateTime2(testdato1, "d. MM. yyyy HH:mm", "no");

String testdato2 = "8. april 2024 15:32";
parseDatoLocalDateTime2(testdato2, "d. MMMM yyyy HH:mm", "no");

How come this does NOT work?
String testdato3 = "8. apr 2024 15:32";
parseDatoLocalDateTime2(testdato3, "d. MMM yyyy HH:mm", "no");

This fails with
java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '8. apr 2024 15:32' could not be parsed at index 3

But why? As far as I can find out, "MMM" is the short name of the month ("apr", "jul" etc.).
I even went "basic", or "idiot", and asked ChatGTP:
Me: Can you show me how to use Java DateTimeFormatter to parse this string into a LocalDateTime object with Norwegian locale: "8. apr. 2024 15:32"

ChatGTP:

String dateString = "8. apr. 2024 15:32";
// Define the formatter pattern with Norwegian locale
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("d. MMM. yyyy HH:mm", new Locale("no"));
    
// Parse the string into a LocalDateTime object
LocalDateTime dateTime = LocalDateTime.parse(dateString, formatter);
    
// Print the parsed LocalDateTime object
System.out.println(dateTime);

And even THIS code doesn't work for me. It fails more or less in the same way:
Text '8. apr. 2024 15:32' could not be parsed at index 7


According to the CLDR, the abbreviated month name for April for Norwegian is "apr.", with a dot.

you can always do something like LocalDateTime.now().format(formatter) to see which format/values the formatter is expecting

Locale.UK is also messed up by CLDR with similar problem. Only from JDK16+, MMM uses 4 characters for just for the month of September.

The code in your edit doesn’t work because there is an extra dot in the format string. “MMM” alone parses “apr.”, so “MMM.” would be expecting “apr..”

The ideal solution is to avoid exchanging date-time data in localized formats. Educate the publisher of your data about the ISO 8601 standard for date-time formats when exchanging date-time values as text.

The ISO standard has absolutely no bearing on usability, and how UX experts decide that information should be presented to normal (often non-computer-literate) users.

When you check the opposite direction. Use your formatter to generate text to verify the human language and cultural norms of your specified locale.
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatterBuilder;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;

DateTimeFormatter formatter = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder().
    parseCaseInsensitive().
    appendPattern("d. MMM. yyyy HH:mm").
    toFormatter(Locale.forLanguageTag("no"));

System.out.println(formatter.format(LocalDateTime.now()));

The output of this snippet (e.g. tested in jshell) is on my machine and at my local time:
8. apr.. 2024 16:29

So the MMM translates to apr. and when you add the . after that, you tell the parser to expect a second dot.
Other way round:
DateTimeFormatter formatterIn = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder().
    parseCaseInsensitive().
    appendPattern("d. MMM yyyy HH:mm").
    toFormatter(Locale.forLanguageTag("no"));
formatterIn.parse("8. apr. 2024 16:29")

That works fine without exception. Note that after the MMM in the format string I didn't add an extra dot.

Thanks. Just what @sweeper pointed out above. It's infuriating that they use different formats for different languages, even though there might be logic behind it.
